# Turning an iPad app into a universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal-binary

I've created an [iPad app](http://github.com/jkooker/OptiActor), and want to turn it into a universal app (i.e. one app that works for iPhone and iPad). The Apple docs seem to only talk about the "Upgrade Current Target for iPad" option. Is there an option to go the other way?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but I think I would start by making a new blank universal app, and then copy in your iPad code/nibs/plists/etc.

Comment: Brute force method - definitely one way to go. Hoping there's a better way than recreating the xcode project.

Answer (score 2):

Open the project in XCode and in the Project menu click "Edit Active Target (...)".
Select "All Configurations" for Configuration.
Under the Deployment heading you'll find "Target Device Family". you can use the search box to locate it.
Edit and select iPhone/iPad to make the application universal.